# Running django on twisted.web

Tags: django, twisted.web

How would you go about running Django on a twisted.web reactor? I haven't been able to find any definitive tutorials that gives solid code examples or anything on github or sourceforge to work off of. I have seen crochet and a few other wrappers but they are all old and out of maintenance. I can use a WSGI but Id rather see if I can run Django as a reactor and try to feed of Stdout and in to control the rest of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi Kyle: you can check out hendrix which we use at my company its pretty cool and does that for you it is simple to run `hx start --dev`... and it uses Tiempo another cool product to do multithreading and monitoring... https://github.com/hendrix/hendrix

Why another Python server?

Gunicorn and uWSGI are great at what they do: listen on a port for requests and pass those requests on to a WSGI app.

> Instead of being first-and-foremost a WSGI container, Hendrix is
>   first-and-foremost a network engine - a Twisted application.
>
> As such, Hendrix is natively able to do threading, asynchrony,
>   websocket traffic, and speak directly to other services in your
>   architecture.

https://github.com/hendrix/hendrix/tree/master/examples/django_hx_chatserver

Comment: So this project lets you run django and twisted reactors on its own with out ANY need to do more of the underlying code? THATS AWESOME!!!!

Comment: I mean you still use: 
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "example_app.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: Is there some good example code to how this is set up this thing looks like it will solve most of my problems!

Comment: I wish I could give you the code we use exactly but you know proprietary... I know that when we get requests that causes a response and then workers from tiempo will do things like mail users and using different API requests.

Comment: If I could even find how to get it set up I am pretty sure I could figure it out from there. Completed source is my best friend

Comment: Did you see the master/example Link I gave?

Comment: Yeah, Im not seeing how to call custom reactors? I see where its fetching django

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92VeMkjM1TQ <- is a video of the core contributor, justin myles demo'ing hendrix

Comment: @KyleSponable: I'm not sure what you mean when you say, "how to call custom reactors."  Do you mean that you want to call methods on the reactor and have them behave as they do in a "normal" twisted app (ie, with the reactor running)?  If so, all you need to do is call .run() on a HendrixDeploy object (as shown in the video above) and everything will just work.